# MYSQL adding and multiplying from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables and here are the values.

```
bom 
----------------
bom_id  | bom_quantity
1       |    1
2       |    4

material_mater 
----------------
material_master_id  |  material_price
1                   |    10
2                   |    4
```

I would like to get the result of this when I multiply the quantity from bom and price from material tables. 
(1*10)+(4*4)=26

How can I do this with a MySQL query?

Comment: What is relation between tables? id?

Comment: bom_id and material_master_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(b.bom_quantity * m.material_price)
FROM bom b, material_mater m
WHERE m.material_master_id = b.bom_id
```

But remember  (1*10)+(4*4)**=26**

(1*10)+(4*4)<>16

Comment: ops, my bad on the calculation part but it worked!! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Janice My pleasure!!

Comment: Hi, I have another question. I have production_hour in routing_has_work_center while production_price in work_center.

The relationship between 2 tables is work_center_work_center_id while for work_center is work_center_id.

This is my query but it doesnt work.

    $query1 = "SELECT SUM(p.production_price*p.production_hour)
    FROM work_center p, routing_has_work_center p 
        WHERE p.production_hour_id = p.production_price_id";

Comment: hmmmm, @Janice, you should not have "p" alias for 2 tables, try p1 and p2, maybe that is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(bom.quantity * material_mater.price)
FROM bom
JOIN material_mater ON material_mater.material_master_id = bom.bom_id
```